# Converting invalid dates in pandas dataframe to nearest valid date

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, error-handling

I have the following dataframe called `df`,

```
Date        Data
05/30/2023  3.733
05/30/2022  3.294
05/30/2021  2.391
02/30/2021  1.807
11/30/2020  1.766
08/31/2020  1.920
05/31/2020  1.830
02/29/2020  2.960
11/30/2019  2.860
08/31/2019  2.680
05/31/2019  2.490
02/28/2019  2.560
11/30/2018  2.560
08/31/2018  2.500
05/31/2018  2.400
02/28/2018  2.310
11/30/2017  2.310
08/31/2017  2.350
05/31/2017  2.510
02/28/2017  2.400
11/30/2016  2.270
08/31/2016  2.220
05/31/2016  2.160
02/29/2016  2.160
11/30/2015  2.055
```

I can see that the 4th entry has an invalid date. (there are only 28 or 29 days in January) I was previously trying to convert the date index using the `pd.to_datetime` function but I kept getting an error. So I tried this.

`df['tempdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')`

That produced this table,

```
Date        Data    tempdate
05/30/2023  3.733   2023-05-30
05/30/2022  3.294   2022-05-30
05/30/2021  2.391   2021-05-30
02/30/2021  1.807   NaT
11/30/2020  1.766   2020-11-30
08/31/2020  1.920   2020-08-31
05/31/2020  1.830   2020-05-31
02/29/2020  2.960   2020-02-29
11/30/2019  2.860   2019-11-30
08/31/2019  2.680   2019-08-31
05/31/2019  2.490   2019-05-31
02/28/2019  2.560   2019-02-28
11/30/2018  2.560   2018-11-30
08/31/2018  2.500   2018-08-31
05/31/2018  2.400   2018-05-31
02/28/2018  2.310   2018-02-28
11/30/2017  2.310   2017-11-30
08/31/2017  2.350   2017-08-31
05/31/2017  2.510   2017-05-31
02/28/2017  2.400   2017-02-28
11/30/2016  2.270   2016-11-30
08/31/2016  2.220   2016-08-31
05/31/2016  2.160   2016-05-31
02/29/2016  2.160   2016-02-29
11/30/2015  2.055   2015-11-30
```

The thing is I have many data frames like this and the errors could be in random months where there are supposed to be 30 days but they show up as 31.

I want to just subtract 3 days from any date that gives me a `NaT` error. But because the dates are not considered dates, I can't seem to subtract the 3 days from them.

Is there a pandas command that I can use to fix this error programatically?

I tried

```
df.index = np.where(df['tempdate'].isna(), pd.to_datetime(df.index), pd.to_datetime(df['tempdate']-np.timedelta64(3,'D')))
```

But I still get an error that the day is out of range.

I also tried breaking the date into different `strings` and converting it to an `int` to minus off 3 days using this,

```
df.index = np.where(df['tempdate'].isna(), df.index, pd.to_datetime(int(df.index.astype(str).str.split('/')[0]),int(df.index.astype(str).str.split('/')[1])-3,int(df.index.astype(str).str.split('/')[2])))
```

But I get this error,

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

What is the best way to deal with errors like this? How do I convert this invalid date to the nearest valid date?

Comment: I think you might be better off asking why you have invalid dates in the first place, and figuring out if you can just drop those rows. If you can't just drop them, you probably have to do the adjustment on the strings and then convert to dates.

Comment: I need to do an adjustment, it can't be fixed from the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert what you can, then use a regex to replace the broken days, then update your previously attempted conversion.

```
def subtract_3_days(match):
    days = int(match.group(1))
    return str(days - 3)

tempdate = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%m/%d/%Y", errors="coerce")
fixed_dates = df.loc[tempdate.isna(), "Date"].str.replace(r"(?<=/)(\d+)(?=/)", subtract_3_days)
tempdate.update(pd.to_datetime(fixed_dates, format="%m/%d/%Y"))

df["proper_dates"] = tempdate
print(df)
          Date   Data proper_dates
0   05/30/2023  3.733   2023-05-30
1   05/30/2022  3.294   2022-05-30
2   05/30/2021  2.391   2021-05-30
3   02/30/2021  1.807   2021-02-27
4   11/30/2020  1.766   2020-11-30
5   08/31/2020  1.920   2020-08-31
6   05/31/2020  1.830   2020-05-31
7   02/29/2020  2.960   2020-02-29
8   11/30/2019  2.860   2019-11-30
9   08/31/2019  2.680   2019-08-31
10  05/31/2019  2.490   2019-05-31
11  02/28/2019  2.560   2019-02-28
12  11/30/2018  2.560   2018-11-30
13  08/31/2018  2.500   2018-08-31
14  05/31/2018  2.400   2018-05-31
15  02/28/2018  2.310   2018-02-28
16  11/30/2017  2.310   2017-11-30
17  08/31/2017  2.350   2017-08-31
18  05/31/2017  2.510   2017-05-31
19  02/28/2017  2.400   2017-02-28
20  11/30/2016  2.270   2016-11-30
21  08/31/2016  2.220   2016-08-31
22  05/31/2016  2.160   2016-05-31
23  02/29/2016  2.160   2016-02-29
24  11/30/2015  2.055   2015-11-30
```

To break it down:

- `tempdate = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%m/%d/%Y", errors="coerce")`
  Convert what we can to datetimes. If it leads to an improper datetime, then we'll end with a NaT value. Store this array into a variable called "tempdate"
- `fixed_dates = df.loc[tempdate.isna(), "Date"].str.replace(r"(?<=/)(\d+)(?=/)", subtract_3_days)`

  - `df.loc[tempdate.isna(), "Date"]` -> wherever `tempdate` has a NaT value, go find the corresponding string back in our original "Date" column from our `df`
  - `.str.replace(r"(?<=/)(\d+)(?=/)", subtract_3_days)` from that subset of strings that didn't convert well, find all of the digits within that array that are surrounded by forward slashes. (e.g. match on this pattern: "/digits/" to just get the digits). Then when we find a match, run it through the `subtract_3_days` function to convert that match to an integer, subtract 3, and return the new value as a string. This leaves any digits that come before or after the slashes (the months and years) untouched. Now we have an array of strings whose "day" values have essentially had 3 days subtracted from them.
- `tempdate.update(pd.to_datetime(fixed_dates, format="%m/%d/%Y"))` Since we fixed our dates, but they're still strings. We need to convert them, and then replace those `NaT` values in tempdate.
- `df["proper_dates"] = tempdate` Finally add in our array/Series back to our original dataframe as a new column.